# Shopping Cart in Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 by Adam Freeman

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shopping-cart

In the **Pro ASP.NET MVC 4** **4th** Edition By *Adam Freeman* and in "*Building the Shopping Cart*" page 219 he defined a *Cart Entity*:

```
 public class Cart
{
    private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();

    public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        CartLine line = lineCollection
            .Where(p => p.Product.ProductId == product.ProductId)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (line == null)
        {
            lineCollection.Add(new CartLine { Product = product, Quantity = quantity });
        }
        else
        {
            line.Quantity += quantity;
        }
    }
      //Other codes

    public class CartLine {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This model is calling from **AddToCart** action method:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = ctx.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productId);

            if (product != null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(product, 1);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }
```

When for the fist time we add a product to shopping cart it adds to ***"lineCollection"*** list. But if we add this product again "**line.Quantity**" increases and "***lineCollection***" *gets update **too*** ("**Quantity**" property of this product in "***lineCollection***" list increases ***too***). And my question is how this update (increase in "***lineCollection***"'s product **Quantity**) happens? We did not change "**lineCollection**" directly?

Sorry for:

- My bad English
- My messy question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line is not a copy of the item in lineCollection. It realy is a reference to the object. You change line, you also change the item in the collection.